# PHP FTP through SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: php, curl, ftp, socks, php-curl

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server through a SOCKS5 proxy in PHP. But I am unable to figure it out. On the internet I do find posts telling me it is possible but in the examples I've found calls like `file_get_contents` are used but I want to use the (native) FTP methods to get all the files in a dir etc.

Is there any way to achieve this? I did found [this](https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/ftp_socks_proxy.asp) extension but I want this to work on all hosts. A composer package would be fine.

Stuff like this does work but this does not allow me to do FTP calls

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://somehost/somefile.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_userpass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo "FTP Transfer: ".curl_exec($ch).PHP_EOL;
curl_close($ch);
```

Just to make it clear: the code listed above works but I'm looking for a way to use the PHP calls like `ftp_get()` and `ftp_put()` through an proxy.

Comment: Do you have an error code or something?

Comment: is `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` supplied in the form `username:password` (user and pass separated by `:`) ?

Comment: "*I want to use the (native) FTP methods to get all the files in a dir etc.*" `curl` will let you get one file at a time

Comment: @AnthonyB "Could not connect" (because it won't go through the proxy). @Paolo the code listed above DOES work but I want to use the native ftp calls like `ftp_get` and `ftp_put`.

Comment: Perhaps there is a kind of _url prefix_ that can be added? Something like "socks5://user@password"? Otherwise it seems there is no option in ftp functions about that.

Comment: @AnthonyB not that I know. I would need to supply a socks server (+user and pass) as well as the ftp server (+ user and pass) so I doubt there is a prefix that supports that (and I can't find any)

Comment: I can't find any option in the ftp functions to use a sock server. I can't find any resource about sock5 prefixes. I think use cURL is a good alternative.

Comment: Yes I might be able to work-around on that but I will need to do more thins manually :( Still open to any suggestions.